# Block-justified comments with ESS

Tags: r, emacs, ess

If I have a line that contains a comment in R, I want it to have the same alignment as the rest of the block where the comment is in.

For example, here's an example of how I like indenting comments:

```
f <- function(x) {
  # the following line adds one
  x + 1
  # the previous line added one
}
```

However, ESS (after pressing TAB) indents my code like this:

```
f <- function(x) {
# the following line adds one
  x + 1
# the previous line added one
}
```

I'm setting the variable `ess-indent-with-fancy-comments` to `nil`, as I like treating `#`, `##`. and `###` equally.

How should I configure ESS so that it indents comments the way I want?

Comment: `ess-fancy-comments` is [marked as obsolete](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/dd1e1444e8abaf6fead6714251cabd56ad4bd2d9/lisp/ess-custom.el#L1074). `ess-indent-with-fancy-comments` is the preferred mechanism. And I can't get it to work with that one, either ...

Comment: I checked my code and was using the correct one (`ess-indent-with-fancy-comments`).  While checking this, I think I found a solution (although I'm not sure why it works).  If in my .init.el file (inside ess-mode-hook) I use `(setq-local ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil)`, rather than `setq`, indentation works well.